# Restoring apple iPad

Tags: ipad, restore

I got an iPad from a friend. It wasn't new, but they reset it so I could start again. The only thing is, I need to get into  the restrictions stuff to change the restriction settings. Problem; I don't have the restrictions pass code. There is no way I can contact the friend since they moved and blah blah blah, I don't have or want a backup, and I can't use iTunes. I am wanting to restore like factory settings, so I can make my own passcode. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Try entering DFU mode and restore it from there.

To enter DFU mode:

Step 1. Connect iDevice with your computer.

Step 2. Start iTunes.

Step 3. Press power- and home-button of your iPhone and hold it down

Step 4. Maybe the “Turn-off” slider will appear – continue holding down both buttons!

Step 5. The iPad will turn off.

Step 6. When the display turns black for four seconds, release the power-button. Don’t release the home-button!

Step 7. iTunes will show you after 5 to 10 seconds that your iPad has entered the DFU mode.

Step 8. Restore Your phone

Hope this helps

Comment: I can't use iTunes.

Comment: I think you should try using redsn0w's restore function. Download link: http://www.iphonehacks.com/download-redsn0w

Comment: Thanks, this worked for our iPad 8th gen (model a2270) on macos ventura. Just putting this comment so that others can find this. All other websites wrote 3 seconds, instead of 4. Didnt seem to get it into DFU mode, with these steps it worked in on go :)

Answer (score 0):

A complete restore of the iPad should turn Restrictions off, so I don't see why they are on, unless the "reset" that your friend did wasn't a restore.

If you can use Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings, this should completely restore the iPad back to factory settings and remove the Restrictions.